# TypeScript 'this' scoping issue

Tags: angular, typescript, this

My code:

```
export class WordService {
    constructor(private http:Http, private storage:Storage){}
    impulseData={
        get():Promise<any>{
            return this.storage.get('impulseData');
        }
    };
}
```

When I call `myWordService.impulseData.get()`, I found `this.storage` is `undefined`. So how can I reach the property `storage` in`impulseData.get`?

I guess this problem was caused by the scoping of `this`. Maybe I should let the `this` inside and outside `impulseData` share the same scope?

**Update:**

Thanks to Suren Srapyan's answer, I finally change my code to this:

```
impulseData={
    get:()=>{
        return this.storage.get('impulseData');
    }
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` refers to the `get()` function's context which doesn't have `storage` property.

You can use `arrow functions`

```
export class WordService {
    constructor(private http:Http, private storage:Storage){}
    impulseData = {
        get: (): Promise<any> => {
            return this.storage.get('impulseData');
        }
    };
}
```

Or Try to get the `this` outside and create the object in the constructor. Also in this case you need to attach your object to `this`, because now it is scoped in the constructor and is not visible outside it, if it is not attached to `this`.

```
export class WordService {
    impulseData;

    constructor(private http: Http, private storage: Storage) {
        const context = this;
        this.impulseData = {
            get(): Promise<any> {
                return context.storage.get('impulseData');
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Or you can use only `storage.get('impulseData')`, if you create in the constructor

Answer (score 0):

In this case you could use the constructor parameter without `this`.

```
constructor(private http:Http, private storage:Storage){
  impulseData = {
    get():Promise<any>{
        return storage.get('impulseData');
    }
  };
```

Otherwise you should use a local variable

```
constructor(private http:Http, private storage:Storage){
  let self = this;
  impulseData={
    get():Promise<any>{
        return self.storage.get('impulseData');
    }
  };
```